# code jquery does'nt work in all posts

Tags: jquery, css, animation, post, blogs

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#img_cont,h3,#txt_right,#dataut,#circle_haut,#read_more,p").mouseover(function(){
         $("#txt_right").css({"opacity": "0.9","transition":"1s"});
        $("#read_more").css({transform: "scale(1)","transition":"1s"});
        $("div#txt_right p").css({transform: "scale(1)","transition":"1s"});
    });
    $("#img_cont,h3,#txt_right,#dataut,#circle_haut,p").mouseout(function(){
        $("#read_more").css({transform: "scale(0)","transition":"1s"});
        $("div#txt_right p").css({transform: "scale(0)","transition":"1s"});
        $("#txt_right").css({"opacity": "0","transition":"1s"});
    });
});
```

I have a website with (html ,css  ,js ,php ,mysql)  i have jquery code i put it for the posts , i mean i change the css property and animation for the post (read more,date.....) on hover mouse ,the problem is the code work only in the first post ,if i create a new post it will work only in this latest post ,and when i hover on an other post the code work in the first code thanx in advance and excuse me for my english am not good .

Comment: instead of ID use CLASS

Comment: ok i will try this thnx :)

Comment: when i used class it's work but in all posts in the same time any ideas and thnx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try to use instead of **ID** use **CLASS**
And use `$(this).css();` so it will not apply to all

Comment: sir , it's coded by php its mean all the posts have the same classes and ids how can i hover in one post

Comment: when you use $(this) it will apply to that particular element

Comment: but iam trying to change the css property for three element on mouse hover in multiple class check the code plz

Comment: now it's work but change css property only for one element